# Position command runs much slower for range containing numerically evaluated Bessel function

Tags: list-manipulation, functions, performance-tuning, timing

I have a long list (about 10000) of positive numbers (here simply denoted `list`), for which I want to find the positions of elements lying between 0.5 and the first zero of the Bessel function of the first kind of order 1, as shown below:

```
Flatten[Position[
   list, _?(0.5 <= # <= 3.83171 &)], 1];
Flatten[Position[
   list, _?(0.5 <= # <= N[BesselJZero[1, 1]] &)],
   1];
```

The first code runs in a fraction of a second whereas the second takes about a minute and I can't figure out why. Please can someone advise what's going wrong? I really want to use the second line  of code because I'm extending it to many ranges involving zeros of Bessel functions, but currently it's taking far too long. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope that this is sufficient for your needs. Essentially, you were using the [**`numerical value`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/N.html) of the BesselZero with [**`MachinePrecision`**](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MachinePrecision.html). You can opt to use the second argument of `N` to obtain the  n‐digit precision of the BesselZero.

```
$Version
```

> [image: version]

```
list = RandomReal[10, 10^5];

Flatten[Position[list, _?(0.5 <= # <= 3.83171 &)], 
  1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> [image: pic1]

```
Flatten[Position[list, _?(0.5 <= # <= N[BesselJZero[1, 1], 6] &)], 
  1] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> [image: pic2]

Comment: Brilliant explanation, thanks bmf!

Comment: @Chris glad I was able to help :)

Answer (score 6):

Speed will suffer if the condition is evaluated inside `Position`on every pass.

*OP - preevaluated condition*

```
list = RandomReal[{0, 5}, 10000];
Flatten[Position[list, _?(0.5 <= # <= 3.83171 &)], 1] // 
  AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> {0.0248739,{1,<<6662>>,10000}}

*OP Slower case*

If you evaluate `(0.5 <= # <= N[BesselJZero[1, 1]] &)` separately, the result is:

> `0.5 <= #1 <= N[BesselJZero[1, 1]] &`

Thus `Position` is presented with an unevaluated condition on every pass, thereby incurring a time penalty.

---

**Workaround**

*Evaluate the upper limit once inside `With`:*

```
With [{a = N[BesselJZero[1, 1]]},
   Flatten[Position[list, _?(0.5 <= # <= a &)], 1]
   ] // AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> {0.0178069,{1,<<6662>>,10000}}

---

Or if you prefer, define and evaluate the upper limit inside the `cond` first:

```
cond = (0.5` <= #1 <= N@BesselJZero[1, 1] // Evaluate) &
Flatten[Position[list, _?cond], 1] // AbsoluteTiming // Short
```

> {0.0169222,{1,<<6662>>,10000}}

---